# How to Convert RoutedEventHandler to EventHandler

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

I got this situation where I need to create a wrapper around a WPF window that exposes basic features, such as exposing Loaded and Closed events. (There are other wrapper implementations for other UI platforms)

```cs
// This works.
public event EventHandler? Closed
{
    add => Ref.Closed += value;
    remove => Ref.Closed -= value;
}

// This doesn't work.
public event EventHandler? Loaded
{
    add => Ref.Loaded += value;
    remove => Ref.Loaded -= value;
}
```

The problem here is that Loaded is a RoutedEventHandled (whereas Closing isn't). Settings an EventHandler doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

Edit: the only solution I can think of is to create a Dictionary of eventhandler wrappers when I add, so that I can get the same reference in remove. Any prettier solution?

Comment: The problem isn't that `Loaded` requires a `RoutedEventHandler`.  It's that you need to be sure that `Ref` is a `FrameworkElement` since that is the level at which the event is exposed.   Once you have a strong type this is that, you can use `+=` and `-=` to your heart's content. So your wrapper should probably be a generic that only works for type `FrameworkElement` or those derived from it.

Comment: Ref is a private field of type `FrameworkElement`, that's fine. I just don't want to publicly expose anything WPF-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the `Loaded` event of `Ref` and raise your own custom event when it's raised:

```
public event EventHandler Loaded;
...
Ref.Loaded += (ss, ee) => Loaded?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this.

```cs
public event EventHandler? Loaded
{
    add
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var handler = new RoutedEventHandler((s, e) => value.Invoke(s, e));
            _loadedHandlers.Add(value, handler);
            Ref.Loaded += handler;
        }
    }
    remove
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            Ref.Loaded += _loadedHandlers[value];
            _loadedHandlers.Remove(value);
        }
    }
}
private Dictionary<EventHandler, RoutedEventHandler> _loadedHandlers = new();
```